# Interpolating 2d array of points

Tags: c#, arrays, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I have a 2d array of points (each point stored in my **Points** struct, which contains only 3 properties: X Y Z), with size of 128x128. I want to interpolate (stretch) this 2d array to greater size (132x132 for example). So far I have managed to interpolate X and Y coordinates of each point using linear interpolation (simply taking coordinates into array of double, interpolating it, and returning it to new 2d array of **Points**). Here is the code of linear interpolation:

```
private double[] InterpolateArray(double[] array, int newLength)
{
    double[] result = new double[newLength];
    result[0] = array[0];
    result[newLength - 1] = array[array.Length - 1];

    for (int i = 1; i < newLength - 1; i++)
    {
        double jd = ((double)i * (double)(array.Length - 1) / (double)(newLength - 1));
        int j = (int)jd;
        result[i] = array[j] + (array[j + 1] - array[j]) * (jd - (double)j);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Problem is that I have no idea how to interpolate Z coordinates of each point. Could that be done same way like X and Y coordinates? Or completely different approach is needed?

Edit: code for my **Points** struct:

```
public struct Points
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }
    public Points(double X, double Y, double Z)
    {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
        this.Z = Z;
    }
}
```

And code which does interpolation (or should do it at least):

```
public Points[,] Interpolate(Points[,] array, int newWidth, int newHeight)
{
    Points[,] result = new Points[newWidth, newHeight];

    double[] bufferBefore = new double[domes.GetLength(0)];
    double[] bufferAfter = new double[newWidth];
            
    for (int i = 0; i < domes.GetLength(1); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < domes.GetLength(0); j++)
        {
            bufferBefore[j] = domes[j, i].X;
        }

        bufferAfter = InterpolateArray(bufferBefore, newWidth);

        for (int j = 0; j < newWidth; j++)
        {
            result[j, i].X = bufferAfter[j];
        }
    }

    bufferBefore = new double[domes.GetLength(1)];
    bufferAfter = new double[newHeight];

    for (int i = 0; i < newWidth; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < domes.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            bufferBefore[j] = result[i, j].Y;
        }

        bufferAfter = InterpolateArray(bufferBefore, newHeight);

        for (int j = 0; j < newHeight; j++)
        {
            result[i, j].Y = bufferAfter[j];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: 1) you mention `Point`, but the example does not show any. 2) you mention a 2d array, but the code is only interpolating in 1D. 3) If your `Points` represents a direction you might have issues with interpolation. So, What is it you are really trying to do?

Comment: @JonasH I edited question and added missing code snippets. About third question: I need to stretch my 2d array to new size: let's say it's initial size is 128x128, and I need to stretch it to 148x128 (for example). And since I got actual points, I need to interpolate them properly for a new size.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any way your current code is correct. In the second part you are doing `bufferBefore[j] = result[i, j].Y;`, but as far as I can see this has not been set anywhere before.

So when interpolating you need to interpolate *all* the values. So you would need to repeat the interpolation for each of x/y/z for each direction.

This however be done a bit simpler by implement the multiply operator for your point struct. This could allow you to do the interpolation for both x/y at once with code looking something like this:

```
public static Vector3 BilinearSample(this Vector3[,] self, in Vector2 point)
{
    var xi = (int)Math.Floor(point.X);
    var xi1 = xi + 1;
    var xf = point.X - xi;
    var yi = (int)Math.Floor(point.Y);
    var yi1 = yi + 1;
    var yf = point.Y - yi;

    // You might need to add checks to ensure the sample is fully inside the image etc.

    var v1 = self[xi, yi];
    var v2 = self[xi1, yi];
    var v3 = self[xi, yi1];
    var v4 = self[xi1, yi1];

    // Do the bilinear sample
    var xfn1 = 1 - xf;
    var v5 = v1 * xfn1 + v2 * xf;
    var v6 = v3 * xfn1 + v4 * xf;
    var result = v5 * (1 - yf) + v6 * yf;
    return result;
}
```

I'm using `System.Numerics` instead of `Point` , but the principle is the same. Note that the above code would be identicalif you change the input/output type to Vector2 or double.

Also note that if the values represents direction or rotation you need to be careful, since the resulting directions might not be normalized after interpolation, and might even be zero.